# Return string with each value separated or null if all are null, using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, for-xml-path

I have a query like this:

```
select stuff (
        (select '; ' + isnull(org.Number, '-')
        from Organization org
        for xml path('')), 1, 2, ''
       )
```

I need to return a string with all values, including nulls, so that its amount of values is equal to amount of organizations, but if ALL values are empty or null, I need to return empty string or null (doesn't matter).

First thought was to use regex and check if there are digits in returned query. but it's not so easy to use. Is there some other options to solve it?

For example, if table Organization contains

```
ID | Number
1  | 123456
2  | null
3  | 3232
```

then resulted string has to be `'123456; -; 3232'`

if table Organization contains

```
ID | Number
1  | null
2  | null
3  | null
```

resulted string has to be `null`

Comment: Hint: `SELECT CASE WHEN ';;;;' NOT LIKE '%[^;-]%' THEN NULL ELSE ';;;;' END`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I added samples.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. I did like this: `select case when (select org.Number from Organization org for xml path('')) not like '%[0123456789]%' then null else stuff (select ...) end`. It works but looks not cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way

```
select
    iif(patindex('%[0-9]%', res) = 0, null, res)
from
    (select res = stuff((
        select
            '; ' + isnull(cast(number as varchar(200)), '-')
        from 
            Organization
        order by id
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
) t
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks! But instead of `iif (...)` I used `case when (res like '%[0-9]%') then res else null end` as db's compatibility level isn't enough to use it and as first character in returned string can be not a digit